# Dropdown problem for selected value other Laravel

Tags: laravel

here i am trying to store the value of "other" in the same column of table.. but it is going null could you please help me find my mistake ?
heres my code :

```
<div class="form-group">
                                    <select onchange="showDiv('hidden_emission_div', this)" name="emission_class" id="emission_class" class="input-lg">
                                        <option selected disabled>Emission Class</option>
                                        <option value="euro-1">Euro 1</option>
                                        <option value="euro-2">Euro 2</option>
                                        <option value="euro-3">Euro 3</option>
                                        <option value="euro-4">Euro 4</option>
                                        <option value="euro-5">Euro 5</option>
                                        <option value="euro-6">Euro 6</option>
                                        <option value="euro-6c">Euro 6c</option>
                                        <option value="euro-6d-temp">Euro 6d-TEMP</option>
                                        <option value="euro-6d">Euro 6d</option>
                                        <option value="other">Other</option>
                                        <input type="text" style="display: none" id="hidden_emission_div" name="manual_emission_class" placeholder="Emission Class*:"/>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <select onchange="showDiv('hidden_engine_div', this)" name="engine_type" id="manual_engine_type" class="input-lg dynamic">
                                        <option selected disabled>Select Fuel*:</option>
                                        <option value="Diesel">Diesel</option>
                                        <option value="Electro">Electro</option>
                                        <option value="Gas">Gas</option>
                                        <option value="Gasoline">Gasoline</option>
                                        <option value="Hybrid">Hybrid</option>
                                        <option value="other">Other</option>
                                        <input type="text" style="display: none" id="hidden_engine_div" name="manual_engine_type" placeholder="Enter Fuel*:"/>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <select onchange="showDiv('hidden_gearbox_div', this)" name="gearbox" id="manual_gearbox" class="input-lg dynamic">
                                        <option selected disabled>Select Gearbox*:</option>
                                        <option value="Automatic">Automatic</option>
                                        <option value="Direct Transmission">Direct Transmission</option>
                                        <option value="Manual">Manual</option>
                                        <option value="Robotic">Robotic</option>
                                        <option value="Robotic dual clutch">Robotic dual clutch</option>
                                        <option value="Robotic one clutch">Robotic one clutch</option>
                                        <option value="Sequential">Sequential</option>
                                        <option value="Variator">Variator</option>
                                        <option value="other">Other</option>
                                        <input type="text" style="display: none" id="hidden_gearbox_div" name="manual_gearbox" placeholder="Gearbox*:"/>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
```

heres my controller:

```
            $store_seller->emission_class = $request['emission_class , manual_emission_class'];
//        $store_seller->emission_class = $request['manual_emission_class'];
        $store_seller->engine_type = $request['engine_type , manual_engine_type'];
//        $store_seller->engine_type = $request['manual_engine_type'];
        $store_seller->gearbox = $request['gearbox, manual_gearbox'];
//        $store_seller->gearbox = $request['manual_gearbox'];
```

[image: If a single value is null from 1 of both names the value of colunm is null]

[image]

i am trying to store the other value in the same column if selected...

this is javascript

```
    function showDiv(divId, element)
{
    document.getElementById(divId).style.display = element.value == 'other' ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

Comment: the hide and show input works?

Comment: yes this its working but conflicting when storing values in DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this way.

```php
$store_seller->emission_class = $request->manual_emission_class ?? $request->emission_class;
```

Comment: the issue is the same brother... when i select other the value stored in DB is other because the initial value of "other" is other... it should store the input type text value instead... :"(

Comment: @Ali ah, sorry I think I got the order wrong, can you try my updated answer?